# XMLQuery in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, xquery

I want to filter some elements from the following database:

```
`CREATE TABLE Club
( name         VARCHAR2(30),
  championship XMLTYPE);`
```

The XML-part looks like this:

```
`INSERT INTO Club VALUES ('FC Arsenal',
'<championship>
    <champion no="13">
        <league>PremierLeague</league>
        <year>2004</<year>
    </champion>
    <champion no="11">
        <league>FA_Cup</league>
        <year>2014</year>
    </champion>
</championship>'
);`
```

I want to filter the name of the club and the year but only if the team won the premier league.

My solution looks like this:

```
`SELECT Name, XMLQuery(
  'for $i in /championship
    where $i/champion/league = "PremierLeague"
    return $i/champion/year
    PASSING Club RETURNING content) As year
FROM Club;`
```

I'm not sure how I can combine the query, so that the name depends on the xmlquery. Now I get all names of the clubs even if the don't won the Premier League. Another problem is that I get the name but the year is (null).

What is wrong?

Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tack it into the where clause as an XMLExists:

```
SELECT Name, XMLQuery(
  'for $i in /championship
    where $i/champion/league = "PremierLeague"
    return $i/champion/year'
    PASSING championship RETURNING content) As year
FROM SPFEV.Club where XMLExists(
  '$i/championship/champion/@league[.="PremierLeague"]'
    PASSING championship as "i");
```

This is syntactically correct and I know the where part is correct, I'm not so sure on the part you did.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now, I'm getting a syntax error - "missing right parenthesis"

Comment: The "passing" name was wrong in your original code. This works for me. If not, there might be a difference in DBMS version.

Answer (score 1):

Since a team might have won more than one year, you might be better off with a XMLTable approach:

```
SELECT c.name, x.year
FROM club c
CROSS JOIN XMLTable('/championship/champion'
  PASSING c.championship
  COLUMNS league VARCHAR2(20) PATH 'league',
    year NUMBER PATH 'year') x
WHERE x.league = 'PremierLeague';

NAME                                 YEAR
------------------------------ ----------
FC Arsenal                           2004
```

This gets both the year and league from the XML, and filters on the league name afterwards.